# Calling a service in angular 2 application in ngInit

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have a clarification in calling a service in angular 2 . Consider the following program:

```
@Component({

 providers : [EmployeeService]
})
export class Employee implements OnInit {

  employees : IEmployee[];

  constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService)
  {
   }

  ngOnInit() 
  {
     this.employees = this._employeeService.getEmployees();
   }

}
```

Why do we have the thumb rule that we need to call the service in **ngOnInit** , normally in any other programming language we would be calling the service for data in the functions only when we need .

But here even though we may or may not need, the data is already fetched from service. Why is it happening?

Comment: There is no such rule, only call when you need it. The idiom is to call it in `ngOnInit` rather than in the `constructor`. This matters for certain framework services and their dependencies.

Comment: Calling in constructor or `ngOnInit` is because code in constructors is hard to test and because some values that you might need to pass to the service might not yet be available in the constructor yet.

Comment: At the constructor, the `html template` is not yet build. When you want to use direct DOM manipulation its recommended to fetch data during `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`, but there is no such rule. You can populate your class properties in any lifecycle (besides DOM wrappers i.e. `ViewChild`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand the angular life cycle hooks **[`ngOnInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)** its get called 
 shortly after creating the component:

If you need to display some data initially in the template the service to fetch data is placed inside **`ngOnInit`**